# Outlook VSTO Addin C# - Catch click event on calendar

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-restapi

I (owner of the mailbox) have some shared calendars, I want catch a email of organizer by click on his calendar (I use this info later on my Add-In).

Owner

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

How and where (which file) can I cache this?

Answer (score 0):

`Explorer.SelectionChange` event will fire even if no appointment is selected in the calendar. Or do you mean when a Calendar folder is selected? Use `Explorer.FolderSwitch` event.

Comment: when i clicked on shared calendar.

Comment: How I can catch  a email of organizer

Comment: Do you mean the email of the mailbox owner? Or the organizer of the selected appointment?

Comment: I mean email of the organizer of selected appointment. (email of the mailbox owner is - Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)

Comment: Namespace.CurrentUser gives you the current user, not the mailbox owner. AppoinmentItem,.Organizer will give you the organizer name.

Comment: AppoinmentItem,.Organizer can you please explain a little more? I got stuck here

Comment: You can loop through the Recipients collection and for each recipient retrieve the `PR_RECIPIENT_FLAGS` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5FFD0003`) using `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` method. Check if the 0x2 bit is set (called `recipOrganizer`) and if yes, use `Recipient.AddressEntry.Address` (for SMTP recipients) or `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`.

Comment: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5FFD0003" is unknown or cannot be found.

Comment: No MAPI property is guaranteed to be present, you must expect and handle exceptions like that. Do you see that property in OutlookSpy (select the appointment, click IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the GetRecipientTable tab)?